# Ruby on rails simple page without database model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner of Ruby and Rails, so this is probably an easy question.

How should I set up a simple page that does not need to have any own database tables? In my case, for example, I have a site storing songs and artists. How I want just a simple HELP page with no intelligence, just static html. I also need a BROWSE page, where the user will select whether to browse for artists or songs. This page will not have any database tables, however it will have a list of links from A-Z, provided the number of posts for each letter, so therefore it needs to have database interaction for tables it does not own by itself.

Should I just create controllers for HELP and BROWSE, or will they need models as well? Using Rails 2, which script/generate tools should I use and what should I ask them to do for me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I usually create a PagesController that shows the static pages like about, faq or privacy.

What you have to do is generate the controller by using

```
script/generate controller pages
```

then add the following in your `config/routes.rb`

```
map.resources :pages, :only => :show
```

In your PagesController

```
def show
  # filter the params[:id] here to allow only certain values like
  if params[:id].match /browse|help/
    render :partial => params[:id]
  else
    render :file => "/path/to/some/404_template", :status => 404
  end
end
```

Then you just need to add partials in `app/views/pages/`

```
#in /app/views/pages/_help.html.erb

<p>This is the help section</p>
```

Comment: Thanks! There were several good candidates for acceptance, but now I've tried them all and this is the one I'll go for. (However, I guess you mean script/generate controller pages. That works anyway).

Comment: Using this method, how can I create a link to /pages/help ?         <%= link_to 'Help', pages_path('help') %> creates a link to /pages.help .

Comment: Thanks for the correction Johan. I updated the post.  As for your question, use page_path('help') instead of pages_path.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't work. I tried browsing to /pages/help.html but it doesn't work. /pages.html doesn't work either. /pages/help doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the approach shown below in the past. Set up a named route in `config/routes.rb`:

```
map.page ':page', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show',
         :page => /browse|help/
```

—Note that the `:page` parameter is constrained to certain values (the URLs `/browse` and `/help`). With this route in place you can create links like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Help', pages_path('help') %>
```

Finally create a controller (`app/controllers/pages_controller.rb`):

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    render params[:page] # => renders /app/views/pages/<page>.html.erb
  end
end
```

You can change the `show` method within the controller if you require more flexibility. For example, you might want to use different layouts for different pages. For that scenario you can branch the logic based on the value of the incoming `:page` parameter.

Comment: +1 Thank you! This is very similar to the one that I accepted. Had to pick one. Sorry. :)

Comment: The pages_path('help') creates a link to /pages.help instead of /pages/help. How can I change that?

Answer (score 1):

Controllers and models are not hardly connected in Rails. It is just a convention. So you can easily create a controller, which will not be connected with any model.

Answer (score 1):

Well if it's pure static (as in *.html) you can just add it in your public folder. For example:

public/test.html 
public/hello.html
public/about.html

Comment: +1 Thanks! It's good to know that this is possible. However, in this case, I like it to make use of a common layout.

Answer (score 1):

it is not compulsory to have a model for each controller. it is just a convention to easily relate

let us consider the page that you want to  display is about_us

add a controller **about_us_controller.rb** with it mentioned in **routes.rb**

add a view **about_us/index.html.rb**

if you want the view not to follow any layout just say

```
 render :layout => false
```

in your about_us.rb

Comment: +1 Thanks! Good to know that this is possible. I went for another way of the suggestions though.